# Flutter error: "The argument type 'Text' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'."

Tags: string, flutter, text, types, variable-assignment

I have following code that was written before and must be updated. I changed `title` to `label` to update the code but it got a new error:

```
      return BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (int index) => _homeScreenBloc.updatePageIndex(index),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedFontSize: 12.0,
        unselectedFontSize: 12.0,
        selectedItemColor: Color(0xFF6BC076),
        unselectedItemColor: Color(0xFF8F8F91),
        iconSize: 26,
        currentIndex: _index,
        elevation: 0,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: Text(_titles[0]),
            icon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: Text(_titles[1]),
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: Text(_titles[2]),
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
          ),
        ],
      );
```

The error message is:

```
The argument type 'Text' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: just pass the String without the Text() widget, like this  `label: _titles[0]` instead of `label: Text(_titles[0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error describes, you cannot assign a Text widget to a String. The label parameter takes a String, not a Text widget. Below should work.

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: _titles[0],
        icon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: _titles[1],
        icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        label: _titles[2],
        icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
      ),
```